# Creating nested fluent API in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

We are trying to come up with fluent API for nested Object.
Consider we have following three classes

Attribute :
    name : String
    Value : Object

Item :
    action : String
    attributes :

Order : 
    action : String
    attributes : 
    items :

Here we want to have fluent API which can help to build above Objects.

Now we need to have builders as follows:

#### Attribute Builder

```
AttributeBuilder.make().name().value().build();
```

#### Item Builder

```
ItemBuilder.make().action()
                   .attribute()
                               .name().value().build()
                   .attribute()
                               .name().value().build()
                    .build();
```

#### Order Builder

```
OrderBuilder.make().action()
                   .attribute()
                               .name().value().build()
                   .attribute()
                               .name().value().build()
                   .item()
                          .action()
                          .attribute()
                                      .name().value().build()
                          .attribute()
                                     .name().value().build()
                          .build()
                    .build();
```

We may later nest the Order Object in Some other object.

So is there any way to achieve such nested DSL building ?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a lot of [Builders](http://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/builder/). Are you sure you need to build each and every detail of the hierarchy like this?

Looking at the code we can see that the entities form a tree-like hierarchy. Orders have items and items have attributes. If the entities are really going to be this simple you could construct the hierarchy without using [Builders](http://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/builder/) at all. See for an example [here](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/blob/master/composite/src/main/java/com/iluwatar/composite/Messenger.java).

For fluent handling of the orders you could employ the [Composite](http://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/composite/) pattern. For example, if you would need to calculate the price of the order based on the items and attributes. Or subtract the ordered items and attributes from the storehouse saldo.